# Multiple Join Operation results GC Overhead Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Hi I am new to Apache Spark.

I am experiencing problem while i am joining seven `CSV` files and then applying `groupBy` over them all the file have same primary key

Example:-

> file1.csv -> (master_id, Some_other_column),
>
> file2.csv -> (master_id,Some_other_column),
>
> file3.csv -> (master_id, Some_other_column),
>
> file4.csv -> (master_id,Some_other_column),
>
> file5.csv -> (master_id, Some_other_column)
>
> file6.csv -> (master_id, Some_other_column)
>
> file7.csv -> (master_id, Some_other_column)

I want to join all the csv file and then Apply `groupBy()` on the basis of `master_id`

Code :-

```
val file1DF = spark.read.options(Map("sep" -> "\t", "header" -> "true", "inferSchema" -> "true")).csv(path)
val file2DF = spark.read.options(Map("sep" -> "\t", "header" -> "true", "inferSchema" -> "true")).csv(path)
```

and so on.
Then i join all the dataframes and after the join I convert the `Dataframe` into `RDD` apply `groupBy` on the basis of `masterId` and store the result in file.

But after some time my code exits with `GC Overhead` problem is there any other way i can achieve the same result.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: GC Overhead can mean a lot of problems, could be in Worker Side, Driver Side, during the Shuffle and so on... Can you add you configuration that you are calling your jobs, Memory and etc?

Comment: spark.executor.memory=2g, spark.executor.core=4, spark.shuffle.partition=200 @ThiagoBaldim Hope this helps. Total csv file input size is around 150MB.